# ASP.Net Session variables - struggling with the Cache

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session-variables

I'm using some session variables to store and pass data across several pages of an ASP.Net application. The behavior is a bit unpredictable though. I'm setting the session variable post page_load as follows

```
Protected Sub Page_LoadComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.LoadComplete
If (Session.Item("ScholarshipID") = Nothing) Then
    Session.Add("ScholarshipID", "Summer2011")
End If
```

Ok so far so good, on a **normal** page load.   If the user completes the form action, hits the next page, and decides OH NO, i needed to change field xyz, and clicks back, corrects the data, then submits, the session variable is showing as NULL.  Why would a cached session behave this way? I'm not destroying/clearing the variable, unless I fail to understand the scope of session variables.

Comment: does the user clicks back on browser window or you have an ASP.net button for it?

Comment: the browser back button. I have not provided a button to traverse backwords in the form-progression.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
If (IsNothing(Session("Scholarship"))) Then
     Session("Scholarship") = "Summer2011"
End If
```